# fork() in a For Loop

Tags: c, process, fork, parent

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/type.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) {
            printf("Fork Error.\n");
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            printf("I am child");
        }
    }

    if(pid != 0) {
        while((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0)
            if(errno == ECHILD)
                break;
            printf("I am parent and all children have exited.\n");
    }
    exit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is that,

'I am child' is printed 7 times,
'I am parent and all children have exited.' is printed 4 times

and the print sequence is not fixed.

Here's my question!

Why 'I am child' is printed 7 times,

and 'I am parent and all children have exited.' is printed 4 times ?

I don't understand the number of times those sentences are printed.

Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: Please take the [tour] again, and read [ask].  Do not post images of code, post the code.  Please [edit] your post, remove the image and post an [mcve].

Comment: please *no* images of code... Also hint: forked process forks

Comment: Print PID numbers on each message (and parent PID — `getpid()` and `getppid()`).  End each message with a newline.

Comment: The condition in the `while (waitpid())` loop is bogus; you just checked that `waitpid()` succeeded, so there is no reason to check `errno` (and every reason not to check it).  You'd do better having the process report on the child that exited (and I'd prefer to see the exit status reported too, but you have to replace `NULL` with `&status`, assuming you have `int status;` defined).

Comment: I erased the image, and posted the code instead. Excuse me for my ignorance

Comment: regarding: `printf("I am child");` in the child process.  If this is not immediately followed by: `exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );` then both the parent and the child will be calling `fork()`, resulting in a LOT more processes than planned upon

Comment: regarding: `if(pid == -1) {
            printf("Fork Error.\n");`  When an error with `fork()` occurs this will stay in the loop, However, (most likely) once `fork()` fails, it will continue to fail.  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. And when the error is from a c library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling: `perror( ("Fork Error" );` which will properly output both your error message and the text reason to `stdout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below. You need to add the wait header. At the same time, after providing the 0 condition of the child processes, you should definitely sign out, otherwise each processes will fork again and again each time in the code. Shortly you have to kill every process after their task end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){

    pid_t pid;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {

            printf("Fork Error.\n");

        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("I am child\n");
            exit(0); // !
        }
    }

    if (pid != 0) {

        while ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0)
            if (errno == ECHILD)
                break;

        printf("I am parent and all children have exited.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it okay if I replace 'exit(0);' with 'break;'?
I tried it and the code output is same,
But I wonder if the 'exit(0)' and 'break' has the same meaning, even if the code output is same.

Comment: `exit(0);` and `break;` do not *mean* the same thing, but in this particular case, they *do* the same thing. `exit(0)` makes the process that calls it terminate completely, `break` makes the thread of execution jump outside of the loop it's in. In this case either is fine, because either way the thread exits cleanly.